How to deactivate the virtual touchscreen keyboard on a notebook with touchscreen?
A keyboard keeps popping up on my Thinkpad T470 with touchscreen. It does not take any input, but the virtual keys light up when touched, so I can't even use the predestined button to minimize it or open its settings. It takes a lot of real estate on the screen and I want to get rid of it alltogether.
In the accessibility settings there is an option for a screen keyboard, but it is already turned off while I experience this behaviour.
A large-language model suggests to execute the following command:
gsettings set org.gnome.desktop.a11y.applications screen-keyboard-enabled false
It results in no return and does not solve the problem
Overall this seems like a common problem as even some extensions exist to specifically block the keyboard like mentioned here. However, I feel like adding something to deactivate something is not a satisfactory solution. It is also not practical at the moment for me as I cannot access the gnome extensions.
What should I do and what even is the issue?
